# Assembly Language using loop for a code

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, addition, nested-loops

I've got this code, but how would I make it using loops. Basically Its a code that takes the first value in the x array and adds it to the next, saves it to the first value in y, then takes the second value from x and adds it to the third and stores it in the second value in y, and so forth. Then it takes the last value of x and adds it to the first value of x and saves it to the last value of y.

```
    .data  
    x   sword   10,20,30,-10,-20, -30  
    y   sword   6 dup (?)

    mov     ax,x                                
    add     x+2,ax  
    mov         y,ax

    mov     ax,x+2                              
    add     x+4,ax  
    mov         y+2,ax

    mov     ax,x+4                              
    add     x+6,ax  
    mov         y+4,ax

    mov     ax,x+6                              
    add     x+8,ax  
    mov         y+6,ax

    mov     ax,x+8                              
    add     x+10,ax  
    mov         y+8,ax

    mov     ax,x+10                             
    add     x,ax  
    mov         y+10,ax
```

Answer (score 1):

> Its a code that takes the first value in the x array and **adds it to the next**, **saves it to the first value in y**, then takes the second value from x and adds it to the third and stores it in the second value in y, and so forth. Then it takes the last value of x and adds it to the first value of x and saves it to the last value of y.

This is an ambiguous wording! "adds it to the next" need not automatically imply writing the sum into the *X* array, just as "saves it to the first value in y" does not necessarily mean that it is the original (before addition) value that goes into the *Y* array. That is how the unrolled code that you show us does it, but it is not how the pseudo code in @SevaAlekseyev's answer does it, so be careful!

The code snippets in my answer do it like *you* have shown because the sentence "Then it takes the last value of x and **adds it to the first value of x** and saves it to the last value of y." seems to tell us just that...

### Writing a loop

The simplest solution uses an address register for the *X* array and another address register for the *Y* array. If this needs to be [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) code then you can choose between BX, SI, DI, and BP. The 'index' registers SI and DI being the logical choices. Since your array has 6 elements but processing the last element is somewhat special, you could initialize the counter in CX to 1 less, so 5, and then process the last element separately outside of the loop. This will avoid having to insert conditional branches:

```
  .data  
    x   sword   10, 20, 30, -10, -20, -30  
    y   sword   6 dup (?)

  mov  di, OFFSET y
  mov  si, OFFSET x
  mov  cx, 5
more:
  mov  ax, [si]         ; mov  ax, x
  add  si, 2
  add  [si], ax         ; add  x+2, ax
  mov  [di], ax         ; mov  y, ax
  add  di, 2
  loop more
  mov  ax, [si]         ; mov  ax, x+10
  add  x, ax            ; add  x, ax
  mov  [di], ax         ; mov  y+10, ax
```

Next is an alternative way that too avoids having to insert conditional branches. Note the extra word at the end of the *X* array that I'll use for a sixth regular iteration followed by a corrective `add` onto the first element of the *X* array. Since we're assuming [8086](/questions/tagged/8086), why not shorten the code using the `lodsw` and `stosw` string primitives:

```
  .data  
    x   sword   10, 20, 30, -10, -20, -30, ?
    y   sword   6 dup (?)

  mov  di, OFFSET y
  mov  si, OFFSET x
  mov  cx, 6
more:
  lodsw                 ; mov  ax, x
  add  [si], ax         ; add  x+2, ax
  stosw                 ; mov  y, ax
  loop more
  add  x, ax            ; add  x, ax
```

And next code shows how you could use a single index instead of separate pointers. The index increments by 2 because it is actually an **offset in the arrays** that hold *word*-sized elements. This snippet also demonstrates that you don't have to use the `loop` instruction per se. In [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) code it is fine but don't use `loop` in 32-bit code where it is a slow instruction:

```
  .data  
    x   sword   10, 20, 30, -10, -20, -30  
    y   sword   6 dup (?)

  xor  bx, bx           ; Current offset in the arrays
more:
  mov  ax, [x + bx]     ; mov  ax, x
  mov  [y + bx], ax     ; mov  y, ax
  add  bx, 2
  add  [x + bx], ax     ; add  x+2, ax
  cmp  bx, 10           ; Continue for the first 5 word-sized elements
  jb   more
  mov  ax, [x + bx]     ; mov  ax, x+10
  add  x, ax            ; add  x, ax
  mov  [y + bx], ax     ; mov  y+10, ax
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to read/write a memory location, you need to use []. [ax] is the memory location at ax, and so on. Works for arrays, too: [x+2] means the second element of x (because they're two bytes each).

Moving on. You can accomplish a loop over array(s) with an index or with running pointers. Let's consider the first.

So you need to run an index (`i`) from 0 to 5. For each value, you need to assign to y[i] the value of `x[1] + x[i+1]`, with the exception of the last one. You'll need a conditional to take care of the last one.

In Intel, there are two registers specifically designed to be indices - `SI` and `DI`. You can address arrays with them premultiplied - constructs like `[array+SI*2]`.

In order to do a loop, you need a conditional jump back: if the index is less than array size, execute the loop again.

So, in pseudocode, deliberately using variable names instead of registers:

```
i=0
Loop:
copy x[i] into y[i] (more than one command in assembly)
if i = array_size-1 then add x[0] to y[i] (conditional jump here)
else add x[i+1] to y[i]

increment i
if i = array_size then jump to loop
```

Comment: *You can address arrays with them premultiplied - constructs like [array+SI*2].* - Not for 16-bit address-size. ([Why don't x86 16-bit addressing modes have a scale factor, while the 32-bit version has it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55657904)).  Increment the register by 2 intead.