# Why don't x86 16-bit addressing modes have a scale factor, while the 32-bit version has it?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, addressing-mode

I'm trying to figure out a reason for the scale factor not being present in the x86 16-bit addressing modes (MASM assembly). While the 32-bit and 64-bit addressing modes have a scale factor. Is there an actual reasoning behind this or it doesn't need it? I would appreciate it if you could explain.

All possible ways different components can be combined to create an effective address:

[image: Image of all possible ways different components can be combined to create an effective address]

Differences between 16- and 32-bit addressing modes

[image: Differences between 16- and 32-bit addressing modes]

Comment: I think the explanation is not strictly technical. X86-16 ISA was designed 40 years ago for processors with 100000 times less transistors than present pentiums. And Intel was probably more interested by designing x86-32 than by upgrading x86-16 ISA when technology improvements  allowed richer instruction sets.

Comment: I know you can only have 5 tags but placing an "x86" tag may be better than the others you chose.

Comment: BTW, your diagrams are wrong.  **32-bit addressing modes can never use a 16-bit displacement**, only 0/8/32.  Maybe that's why it's bolded in red in your 2nd one?  Code in 32-bit mode can *use* 16-bit addressing modes, but that limits you to 16-bit registers as well (and only `BX|BP + SI|DI`)

Answer (score 6):

**16-bit addressing modes only allow a single ModRM byte** to encode the register (3 bits), mode (2 bits) and the register/memory operand (3 bits), so there's no room to encode a scale factor, or even to let arbitrary registers be bases or indices.  [NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes) lists them all, it's not a long list!  Just subsets of `(BP|BX) + (DI|SI) + disp0/8/16`.  Remember that in an instruction like `add cx, [bx+si]`, the register destination needs the 3 bit `/r` field in ModRM to encode which of the 8 GP registers.

(The 2-bit "mode" signals whether it's a register or memory, e.g. `add bx, cx` vs. `add [bx], cx`, and how many immediate displacement bytes there are: disp8 / disp16 or no displacement.)

**In 32/64-bit addressing modes, the r/m field in ModRM can be an escape code that signals the presence of a SIB byte (Scale/Index/Base)**, which gives room to encode scaled-index addressing modes with a 2-bit shift count.

And also enough coding space to let us use any register as a base, and any register (except ESP) as an index.  So 32-bit addressing modes make the registers more orthogonal.  See [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base) for the details on the escape sequences, e.g. `[esp]` always needs a SIB byte because the encoding that would mean base=ESP is the escape code for the presence of a SIB byte.

See https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#32.2F64-bit_addressing_2 or the ModRM/SIB tables in Intel's manuals for more details.