# Any useful way (amd64) to effect a transfer like this? pc <-- (sp) [Note the absense of auto-decrement]

Tags: optimization, x86-64, opcode

That's it.  Seems to be specifically absent.

Just read ('red') the instruction set, I don't see an obvious way to do this?

Looking for a way to get the same result, shorter is better of course.
(Have not looked at ARm yet, but in case you happen to already know the answer, ...)

Comment: You mean like `ret` but without popping the return address?  `jmp [rsp]`.  Unless you actually mean the (SP) part, truncating the stack-pointer address to 16-bit.  You can't AFAIK do that in one instruction, since 16-bit address-size doesn't allow SP as a base or index.  (And 16-bit address-size isn't available in 64-bit mode.)

Comment: Yes, exactly-like ret but without popping the return address. And no, not truncating, just used the parens to mean "indirect, or contents-of".  What I read seemed to indicate that the sp register could not be used for register-indirect jumps.  Thanks, I'll look again.

Comment: I meant that `sp` is the name of the low 16 bits of the 64-bit stack pointer, `rsp`, but it could also be a generic placeholder for "stack pointer" like how "pc" is generic for RIP. You're right that `jmp [sp]` isn't a valid instruction, but `jmp [esp]` and `jmp [rsp]` are both valid. Like I said, it's only 16-bit addressing modes that have that limitation ([Why don't x86 16-bit addressing modes have a scale factor, while the 32-bit version has it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55657904)).  You tagged this x86-64 so I guessed you were talking about 64-bit mode, not 16-bit legacy or compat mode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, sorry--I meant it generically, as "stack pointer", and in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Yes, sorry--I meant it generically, as "stack pointer", and in 64 bit mode. I also neglected to catch the fact that, even generically, while (sp) is equivalent to contents at 'top-of-stack', they are not actually interchangeable.  Unless one is actually thinking of the physical hardware, but I wasn't.   I'm thinking VM, but did an overly specific transliteration to (sp),  when I *really* meant top of stack,, confusing both of us. The former is a memory reference, the latter is already in a register.  Sigh.  Thanks Peter.